# How does java apps redirect the .do extension

Tags: java, url

How does java apps redirect the `.do` extension? Do they really own a domain with a `.do` extension or is it something like they redirect the `.do` domain to some another domain?

Comment: In web application if we want to hide our names of the pages and other stuff in url then we will map to some other extension ie).do. So you will get an display of .do in url. Apart from that there is no redirection of domain names here

Comment: Because You don't give sample, we will guess: web environment? Servers are quire sophisticated and have MANY rules for administration

Comment: "Extension" has no meaning outside a DOS/Windows environment. You need to be a lot more specific, preferably with examples.

Comment: Example :www.example.com/register.do

Comment: but can i do the same using php?

Comment: PHP? yes, but not fresh "unzipped", best to have some framework with `controller`. or manual Apache configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no domain related concept here. Web application frameworks are using the concept of `Request Mapping`. They're getting a request and searching for a controller method that matches that requested url. If such a match exists, that controller method would be called and after execution, a result will return to client. For example, in Spring MVC:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserService {
    @RequestMapping("/register.do")
    public void registerUser(User user) {
        // user registration stuff
    }
}
```

Any request to `/users/register.do` url would be handed to `registerUser` method to process. Each framework has its own mechanics of doing this mapping but the concepts would be the same. There is no domain realted stuff.